# How to remove a scratch from an image using matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

Let's say I have this image [this](https://picasaweb.google.com/113201095350972874862/December272011#5690808415469359186):

[image]

With a black scratch and I want to remove it from my image. I know it is noise. I have tried neighbourhood filter and also gaussian filter but no success.

Comment: It would be useful to know what, if anything, you have tried already.

Comment: Well for once i have thought that we could identify the pixels which are corrupted by noise and apply filtering.. identifying a filter for this purpose is a task at hand

Comment: i tried the median filter it works but blurs the image a great deal however i first converted it into a gray image... what if i want to remove a scratch from an RGB image

Comment: Is the location of the scratch known?

Comment: No its not .. i have to somehow detect the region and develop a means to remove it

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you know the location of the scratch, this problem is known as [inpainting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inpainting), and there are very sophisticated algorithms for that. So one approach would be to detect the scratch as good as you can, then use a standard inpainting algorithm on it. I've played with your image in Mathematica a little:

First I applied a median filter to the image. As you found out yourself, this removes the scratch, but also removes a lot of detail. The difference between median and original image is a good indicator for your scratch, though:
[image: difference between median and original image]

When I binarize this image with a manually selected threshold, I get a quick&dirty scratch detector:
[image: Binarized]

If you have more knowledge about what your scratches look like, you can improve this detector a lot. e.g. are the scratches always dark? Do they always have high contrast? Are they always smooth curves, i.e. is their curvature always low? - Each of these properties can be measured somehow, so you'd combine these measurements to a single image and binarize that.

One small improvement is to remove small components:
[image: DeleteSmallComponents]

This is still not perfect, but the result is good enough to use it as an inpainting mask:
[image: inpainting]

This will remove some detail, too, but the differences are harder to spot.

Full Mathematica code:

```
difference = ImageDifference[sourceImage, MedianFilter[sourceImage, 2]];
mask = DeleteSmallComponents[Binarize[difference, 0.15], 15];
Inpaint[sourceImage, mask]
```

**EDIT:**

If you're don't have access to a standard inpainting algorithm (like Navier Stokes or Telea), a poor man's algorithm would be to use the median filtered image in those regions where the mask is 1 (probably something like `mask*sourceImage + (1-mask)*medialFilteredImage` in Matlab). Depending on the image data, the difference might not be worth the extra effort of a "real" inpainting algorithm:

[image: Poor man's inpainting]

Comment: really good thanks ! what i did as u said is firstly , applied a median filter with mask [5 5] Secondly subtracted my image with the original image and received the first image , Thirdly what i did is binarized the image with threshold 0.7 and got the image https://picasaweb.google.com/113201095350972874862/December27201102#5690835622483741362 is there anyway i can remove the scratch i have detected and remove it from this

Comment: @user1009156: Mathematica, IPP, OpenCV all have built in inpainting-functions, so I never had to implement it myself. It's not trivial. Easiest way is probably to google for "Inpainting+Matlab" and look for code samples.

Comment: Look into academic papers about "level lines" for inpainting and disocclusion. The technique can handle fairly significant damage to photos.

Some papers:

"Level Lines Based Disocclusion" by Masnou and Morel
math.univ-lyon1.fr/~masnou/fichiers/publications/icip.pdf

"Image Inpainting" by Bertalmio, Sapiro, Caselles and Ballester

Answer (score 0):

A [filter for Avisynth](http://avisynth.org.ru/despot/despot.html) and a [plugin for VirtualDub](http://spotremoverfilter.com/) (my two favourite video editing tools). It will hardly get better than these two (You can learn from them if you really need to implement it yourself).

Answer (score 0):

My result using median filter with ImageJ

[image]