# Calculate Median Image in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, median

I am new to matlab, so forgive me if i am asking for the obvious here: what i have is a collection of color photographic images (all the same dimensions). What i want to do is calculate the [median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median) color value for each pixel.

I know there is a median filter in matlab, but as far as i know it does not do exactly what i want. Because i want to calculate the median value between the entire collection of images, for each separate pixel.

So for example, if i have three images, i want matlab to calculate (for each pixel) which colorvalue out of those three images is the median value. How would i go about doing this, does anyone know?

---

*Edit: From what i can come up with, i would have to load all the images into a single matrix. The matrix would have to have 4 dimensions (height, width, rgb, images), and for each pixel and each color find the median in the 4th dimension (between the images).
Is that correct (and possible)? And how can i do this?*

Comment: Incidentally, the median filter is for doing things like [scratch removal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645515/how-to-remove-a-scratch-from-an-image-using-matlab).

Comment: @Li-aungYip, yeah i know, completely different from what i'm trying to do. But i just thought i'd mention it, to let people know i've considered adapting it to my needs.

Comment: I know you know (and it's good that you investigated it yourself!) but it was new to me, and I thought it was cool. ;)

Comment: @Li-aungYip, yeah it is, matlab in general is awesome! just discovered it, and it's a lot better than coding this all by hand in processing :).

Comment: Just remember: when you get sick of MATLAB's strange quirks, there's also `numpy`/`scipy`. ;) (Not like I can talk: I [did my thesis in MATLAB](http://www.penwatch.net/cms/?p=24).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding my comments into a full answer;

@prototoast's answer is elegant, but since medians for the R, G and B values of each pixel are calculated separately, the output image will look very strange.

To get a well-defined median that makes visual sense, the easiest thing to do is cast the images to black-and-white before you try to take the median.

`rgb2gray()` from the Image Processing toolbox will do this in a way that preserves the luminance of each pixel while discarding the hue and saturation.

*EDIT:*

If you want to define the "RGB median" as "the middle value in cartesian coordinates" this is easy enough to do for three images.

Consider a single pixel with three possible choices for the median colour, `C1=(r1,g1,b1)`, `C2=(r2,g2,b2)`, `C3=(r3,g3,b3)`. Generally these form a triangle in 3D space.

Take the Pythagorean distance between the three colours: `D1_2=abs(C2-C1)`, `D2_3=abs(C3-C2)`,  `D1_3=abs(C3-C1)`.

Pick the "median" to be the colour that has lowest distance to the other two. Defining `D1=D1_2+D1_3`, etc. and taking `min(D1,D2,D3)` should work, courtesy of the [Triangle Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality). Note the degenerate cases: equilateral triangle (C1, C2, C3 equidistant), line (C1, C2, C3 linear with each other), or point (C1=C2=C3).

Note that this simple way of thinking about a 3D median is hard to extend to more than three images, because "the median" of a set of four or more 3D points is a bit harder to define.

**Edit 2**

For defining the "median" of N points as the centre of the smallest sphere that encloses them in 3D space, you could try:

1. Find the two points N1 and N2 in {N} that are furthest apart. The distance between N1 and N2 is the diameter of the smallest sphere that encloses all the points. (Proof: Any smaller and the sphere would not be able to enclose both N1 and N2 at the same time.)
2. The median is then halfway between N1 and N2: `M = (N1+N2)/2`.

*Edit 3*: The above only works if no three points are equidistant. Maybe you need to ask math.stackexchange.com?

*Edit 4*: Wikipedia delivers again! [Smallest circle problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest_circle_problem), [Bounding sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_sphere).

Comment: i know formally the median can only be found on data that can be arranged from high to low (which is why you mean it only makes sense for black and white images, because rgb-color has three different values, right?). But what i want to do is use it for color data, preferably keeping rgb values together. So the median i'm looking for would then be the point in a 3d space (on the xyz-axes are all the rgb values for that specific pixel, arranged high to low) that is closest to the middle (in all three directions). That's what i am trying to calculate.

Comment: Maybe you need to use a different colour space that looks more like a polar coordinate system (HSV/HSL?)

Comment: I've tried that, but a hsv median is not as attractive to me. It just looks less natural than an rgb median (for example: usually an hsv mean turns green, with a sufficient amount of images).

Comment: Do you think i would have to use some sort of pathfinding algorithm, or is there a simpler way? (i'm thinking of the 3d space with all the values, with an orb with an increasing radius r emanating from the middle, until it hits a value (which is then the median), if that's not too abstract:)

Comment: thank you! i'll get to trying this! i'll try this with three images first, then we'll see how it can be expanded to fit more images.

Comment: @SamuelKiely: It depends if you want to constrain the median to be one of the original values. If you want to define the median as "the centre of the smallest sphere that encloses all the RGB points in 3D space", then that's doable but the resulting colour will not be one of the original input RGB points.

Comment: it's important that it's an original input point, so i'll try the minimal bounding sphere approach. Use that to find the center, and then try to find the closest original datapoint to that center. I've found a matlab function that could be of use here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34767-a-suite-of-minimal-bounding-objects.

Comment: Just so long as you keep in mind that this no longer bears any resemblance to the statistical definition of the median. ;)

Comment: i know, it's just that the median was the best i could come up with. But i have found something better; the medoid (suitable to multidimensional data, and always returns a member of the dataset). Wikipedia to the rescue again :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medoid

Comment: Aren't you making this too complicated? I thought the median was simply the middle value of an ordered series of values?

Comment: @aaronsnoswell: The OP was asking to find the median of pixel colours, each of which is a triplet of (Red, Green, Blue). How do you define the median value of three triplets, [2,45,92] , [23,65,18] , [223,14,182]? There's no natural or straight-forward way to order triplets of numbers against each other.

Answer (score 7):

Your intuition is correct.  If you have images image_1, image_2, image_3, for example, you can assign them to a 4 dimensional matrix:

```
X(:,:,:,1) = image_1;
X(:,:,:,2) = image_2;
X(:,:,:,3) = image_3;
```

Then use:

```
Y=median(X,4);
```

To get the median.

Comment: +1 for an elegant solution. Though defining the "median" colour for an RGB pixel is a bit iffy; as it stands, you've taken the median of R, G and B separately, which will yield a very strange looking image.

Comment: @Li-aungYip, you're right. Is there a way to keep the values together?

Comment: Well it depends how you want to define the "median" of coloured pixels. If you're dealing with photos, for example, the "median" only makes sense if you cast the photos to black and white. What's your use case here?