# how I can calculate median,min magnitude of image in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, fft, ifft

I have a image and in my homework I must calculate fourier transform of it and recover it by 3 different value

- with min of magnitude values
- with median of magnitude values with 25%
- percentage of magnitude values

my main picture is

[image]

and after run my script

[image]

```
I=imread('image number one.bmp');
gI=rgb2gray(I);
imafft = fft2(single(gI));
% Gets magnitude and phase.
 mag = abs(imafft);
 phi = angle(imafft);
 % Generates the modified spectrum
 magvector=mag(:);
 myones=ones(size(mag));
 percent25 = prctile(magvector,25);
 minfft = min(magvector).*exp(i*phi);
 medianfft = myones .* median(magvector).*exp(i*phi);
 percentfft = myones.*percent25.*exp(i*phi);
 figure;
 subplot(131);
 imagesc(abs(ifft2(minfft)));
 title('with min of magnitude');
 subplot(132);
 imagesc(abs(ifft2(medianfft)));
 title('with median of magnitude');
 subplot(133);
 imagesc(abs(ifft2(percentfft)));
  colormap(gray);
 title('with 25 percentage of magnitude');
```

Is my result correct and recovering image with min and median and 25% of magnitude are similar each other?

**my main question and problem is really how I calculate median of magnitude?**

apreciate any help

Comment: I think you may try some benefit from this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342602/calculate-median-image-in-matlab

Comment: @fpe I need implement of it exactly, do u know How can I achieve this job?